# Design patterns to change enum?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, enums

I'm having a problem with using enums. Let's say I have defined enum which names DeviceType's which is used by outside clients to specify Devices which they want to use from my Devices container. But as enum's are not expandable I can not have new devices without updating my library and having all users update to new version. I'm looking for as simple solution to this problem as possible. I don't want to use attributes or any other .NET "cheating" goodies.

```
public class Program
{
    private static List<IDevice> devices;

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        devices = new List<IDevice>()
        {
            new NetworkDevice()
        };
        IEnumerable<IDevice> currentDevices = GetDevices(DeviceType.Network);

        IEnumerable<IDevice> newDevices = GetDevices(DeviceType.NewNetwork); // Will not work, unless client updates my library to get newly added enum types
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IDevice> GetDevices(DeviceType type)
    {
        return devices.Where(device => device.Type == type);
    }
}

public enum DeviceType
{
    Network
}

public interface IDevice
{
    DeviceType Type { get; }
}

public class NetworkDevice : IDevice
{
    public DeviceType Type
    {
        get
        {
            return DeviceType.Network;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: may be just use `Dictionary` instead of enum?

Comment: It sounds basically like you are saying "I want to use an enum, but an enum can't do what I want". I suggest not using an enum.

Answer (score 2):

Using an enum to represent a type often means that you should be making class hierachy.

Similarly, `switching` on an enum that represents a type usually means that there's one or more virtual methods wanting to be introduced somewhere into that hierarchy.

How do intend to use the enum type? Is there a way to represent its usages as calls to virtual methods instead?

(The code in your question shows devices of a particular type being filtered for, but it doesn't show what methods you call for those items after they've been found.)

[EDIT] As an alternative, you could go full-nuclear with this and use the [`Managed Extensibility Framework`](http://mef.codeplex.com/). That kind of violates your "no cheating" stipulation though... ;)

Comment: I am happy to NOT use enums but I don't know how to change class structure so that it could support new devices being requested from client code. As for usage client code would just use IDevice interface methods (let's say "void Init()" and so on", but it will use particular implementation through inheritance.

Comment: @user2528957 It really does sound like you need a "plug-in" architecture like that Managed Extensibility Framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to us a `List<string>` and populate it from some backend datastore.  With this you can update the datastore with the valid values to use for the related `List<string>`.

```
public enum DeviceType
{
    Network
}
```

would no longer need to exist, and you would update IDevice to just use a string

```
public interface IDevice
{
    string Type { get; }
}
```

@Matthew has a great point. However, if your primary concern is being able to changes the values without recompiling the code, something similar to the above would be required.